# Simple postfix relay server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I want to set up a postfix server that relays emails to another email address.

I have an ubuntu server set up, a domain name (myvps.be) and a database of users. I want to make it so that when someone sends a mail to username@myvps.be it is relayed to the users personal mail.
Postfix doesn't has to be connected to the database, I can do this with a config file. I would like to do this as simple as possible.

I have already found several tutorials, but all of the require authentication or other things I don't want.

Is there a tutorial or someone who knows how to do this? It doesn't have to be postfix either, I just want this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this tutorial useful. This is not about a relay mail server but about mail forwarding.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this email forwarding via virtual file.

You can found this file in Postfix directory in virtual file. 
You just add this line
`username@myvp  personal_email_id`

After that, you must update the virtual database using

`postmap 'path of the virtual file'`

then restart the postfix.